# Slide Encima do Menu

Tags: html, bootstrap-3

Olá, eu gostaria de deixar meu menu sobrepondo o slide no boostrap mas quando adiciono o slide , ele fica em cima do menu, como esta na imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é meu index onde esta o slide

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Auto Jet - Serviços Automotivoss</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/geral.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/plugins.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

         
                 <div class="carousel-inner">
                     <div class="item">
                        <img src="slide1.png" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
                     </div>                  
                     <div class="item active">
                          <img src="slide2.png" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
                    </div>
                     <div class="item">
                          <img src="slide3.png" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">                      
                    </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" ></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Próxima</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <img src="images/logo-home.svg" alt="logo topo">
                </div>
            <div class="links">
                <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="servicos.html">Serviços</a></li>
                <li><a href="contato.html">Contato</a></li>
            </ul>   
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        </header>

         <main>
              <section class="sobre">    
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="itens">
                            <div class="imagem">
                                 <img src="images/logo-quem-somos.svg" alt="Logo Quem somos">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="textos">
                            <p><strong>A AutoJet®</strong> é uma empresa especializada em serviços automotivos,atuando a mais de 10 anos no ramo de mecanica, com professionais capacitados para atender ao que for preciso para seu veiculo, visando atendimento rapido e efeciente...</p>
        
                            <a href="sobre.html" class="botao medio"> <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> Continue Lendo</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </section>
         </main>
        <footer>
            <div class="logo-rodape">
                 <a href="index.html">
                    <img src="images/logo-rodape.svg" alt="logo-rodape">
                 <a/>
            <p> Todos os Direiros Reservados Auto Jet Serviços Automotivos ® - 2017 </p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Uns brs não resolve isso ai não?!

Comment: O br, não serve para pular as linhas ?, no caso o slide continuaria descendo junto com o menu, por ser containers diferentes